# As a normal user, how would I know how many arguments and what arguments I need to pass in a command line arguments program?

Tags: python, arguments, command, line

As a user, how would I know how many arguments and what arguments I need to pass in a command line arguments program, since there is no input function applied to the script with some sort of indication stating, enter your name or age or etc...or how a user know that age comes first or name come first or address ?

just a general question for my understanding, as im going through a python learning process.

Comment: Generally, programs will have a `--help` option that tells you what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if the program isn't in any way interactive and replies entirely on arguments from the command line, then the best way to know its argument criteria is to ask it. Typically the argument `--help` will produce a list of available options and how to use them, like so: `ls --help`, or `python somescript.py --help`.

The exact option required to get help may vary from program to program. On MS-DOS `/?` was common, and some older Unix programs used `-?`, but generally speaking `--help` has been a standard convention for quite some time, and you should try that first before looking for other options.

Btw, if you want to write Python programs that output their own help information, there's handy libraries such as argparse that handle most of the hard work for you. The argparse library (a standard part of Python) accepts a specification of the types of arguments your Python script will accept, and it will validate the user's command line arguments for you to check they meet your requirements, and even print out the --help information or error messages as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to write programs in such a way that an error is raised if you specify the wrong number of arguments.

And you can always open the program itself and take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

A normal user **(Note: I mean only the user, and not a programmer or developer)** doesn't need to know how many arguments or what arguments are required. It is the responsibility of the developer to give the program user friendly. For instance, for giving the approximate age of a user, user is asked to give only the year of birth. Whereas, if the program needs to give the accurate age, the user will be asked to give date, month and year of birth.

In either cases, the user doesn't need to remember what arguments to give. Because, the user is going to answer only the questions they  are asked.

Coming to the second part of the question, Being a programmer, if you don't know which argument to write first and which next, There are better ways to call a function.

you can very well call a function like `function_name(age=25, name='Pratik Vaidhya')`. Here the order of the arguments doesn't matter if you mention the arguments' name as well. But remember, you must stick to the spelling and capitalisation as per the syntax.

Comment: thank you very much !!! this is very informative.. but i still have a small doubt.. what about in cases like if you require multiple arguments and some or more than one arguments are needed in int form then how will a specific int value match to its corresponding parameter?

Comment: I guess this is what you're asking about. If you see in the above example itself, I've mentioned age without quotes i.e `age = 25` whereas the name I have mentioned within quotes i.e `name='Pratik Vaidhya'`. What I mean to say is only string needs to be mentioned inside quotes. If there were no quotes, the function should be written accordingly whether it is a int or float. Unlike many other languages, in python you don't need to mention the type of variables.

Comment: no, no I got the understanding of how INT or STRING is written in a script. My question is when you have keyword type parameters in a function and more than one parameter require INT arguments... so in case of command-line-arguments, without knowing the order, how will a program   map multiple INT arguments with its correct corresponding  parameter?

Comment: Let us  assume that a function is written with arguments say `def func_name(name, age, height)`. If you want to call the function without arguments name, you should stick to the order like `func_name('Pratik Vaidhya', 25, 170)`. If you doon't know the order, you can write `func_name(name='Pratik Vaidhya', height=170. age=25)`. Either the order should be the same or the arguments' name should be mentioned for the function to decide which integer is meant for which argument.